# How to write non-brittle rspec tests for DateTime values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails app I have a model attribute that sets a datetime when the user performs an action.

What is the best way to test for this functionality, without being too brittle?

for example, I have

```
it "should set the uploaded time" do
  @model.uploaded_at.should == DateTime.now.new_offset(0)
end
```

My test is failing when it should pass, with

```
expected: Thu, 24 May 2012 10:32:50 +0000
got: Thu, 24 May 2012 10:32:50 UTC +00:00
```

So my questions are:

1. How should I define `DateTime.now.new_offset(0)` so that the UTC
   marker is expected?
2. I can see this test potentially failing due to
   the passage of time. For example: factory get created, tests are
   run, 1 second later `it "should set the uploaded time"` is run,
   test fails due to 1 second difference. Is there a better way to test
   this?

Thanks for any tips that would help me learn this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is timecop for that purpose
https://github.com/jtrupiano/timecop

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, if you don't want to add another gem (timecop), you can stub the date (`DateTime.stub(:now).and_return :whatever`) or base your test on the fact that `uploaded_at` changed (`@model.uploaded_at.should_not == the_previous_uploaded_at_value`)

Comment: thanks. This is useful. I'm going to use timecop in this case, as I have some other time based things to test. But your answer will be useful. Shame I can't mark two answers!